# Android: Include Timestamps in logcat via ACRA

Tags: android, logcat, acra, acralyzer

I am using the following ACRA config to send me an email when my application crashes:

```
@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "", // will not be used
mailTo = "myaddress@gmail.com", // my email here
customReportContent = {ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE, ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME, ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION, ReportField.PHONE_MODEL, ReportField.STACK_TRACE, ReportField.LOGCAT },
mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text,
logcatArguments = { "-t", "1000", "myapp*:V"  }
)
```

This will send me an email with all of the logcat Text output but how do I include the Time field shown in Logcat?

I have tried adding "time" to the logcatArguments but that does nothing at all.

I could modify the content of my output text to include the time but that won't help for other system events that I may be interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I need the "-v" as well. This works:

```
logcatArguments = { "-v", "time", "-t", "1000", "myapp*:V" }
```